# Angular Expressions {{}} are not working in flask even after modifying the start and end interpolation tags

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask, jinja2

I am new to angular js , flask . I am working on a simple web app. I am displaying a list of records retrived from databse on a web page where I used double opening and closing curly brackets as an expression but it did not work as Flask uses Jinja2 engine to render the templates and Jinja2 also uses double curly braces {{ }} to insert values. Hence, I used a a solution given in this [link](http://codehandbook.org/angularjs-not-working-in-python-flask-web-app/)  . It works for the separate/single expressions but the not for the data I am displaying as list in a table.

The error message I get in the title of the tab is

> "TemplateSyntaxError:Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'. //Werkzeug
>   Debugger"

Here is my angular code

```
<script>
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myname = "Howdy !!";
}])
.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//').endSymbol('//');
});
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
        //myname//
        <table>
        <caption> Todo List</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="addText" name="text" ng-model="addMe">
                        <input type="submit"  name="my-form" value="Add Task" >

                    </td><td>
                    Search :<input type="text"> 

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task Id</th>
                    <th>Task</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                {% for user in User %}
                <tr ng-repeat= "user in User">
                    <td>
                    //user.uid//

                    </td>
                    <td>//user.taskname//

                        <span style="padding-right:3px; padding-top: 3px; display:inline-block;" ></span>
                        <input type="image" class="deleteImg" src="static/img/trash_can.png" height="15px" width="18px" name="removeId" value={{user.uid}} ></input> 
                         <input type="image"  id='addButton' src="static/img/editbtn.svg" height="15px" width="18px" name="editId" value={{user.uid}} ></input>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think the interpolation start and end symbols need to be unique. You cannot use `//` for both start **and** end

Comment: Hi @Phil I tried changing the end tag but it did not work.

Comment: I've constructed test example based on your html and everything is working fine, so I suppose the problem might be outside of what you've showed us. The exception with werkzeug means that problem is in flask, not angular. So I'd advise you to review and debug your html code.